# unable to link to gettimeofday on embedded system, elapsed time suggestions?

Tags: c, embedded, arm, gettimeofday

I am trying to use gettimeofday on an embedded ARM device, however it seems as though I am unable to use it:

```
gnychis@ubuntu:~/Documents/coexisyst/econotag_firmware$ make
Building for board: redbee-econotag
       CC obj_redbee-econotag/econotag_coexisyst_firmware.o
LINK (romvars) econotag_coexisyst_firmware_redbee-econotag.elf
/home/gnychis/Documents/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none- eabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-gettimeofdayr.o): In function `_gettimeofday_r':
gettimeofdayr.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_gettimeofday'
/home/gnychis/Documents/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [econotag_coexisyst_firmware_redbee-econotag.elf] Error 1
make: *** [mc1322x-default] Error 2
```

I am assuming I cannot use gettimeofday() ?  Does anyone have any suggestions for being able to tell elapsed time? (e.g., 100ms)

Comment: This error seems to indicate that your standard library installation is badly broken...

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is create your own _gettimeofday() function to get it to link properly.  This function could use the appropriate code to get the time for your processor, assuming you have a free-running system timer available.

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int _gettimeofday( struct timeval *tv, void *tzvp )
{
    uint64_t t = __your_system_time_function_here__();  // get uptime in nanoseconds
    tv->tv_sec = t / 1000000000;  // convert to seconds
    tv->tv_usec = ( t % 1000000000 ) / 1000;  // get remaining microseconds
    return 0;  // return non-zero for error
} // end _gettimeofday()
```

Comment: Any idea what __your_system_time_function_here__ might be?

Comment: It entirely depends on your hardware and how you access the system timer, if you even have one available.

Comment: Where should this be defined? I added it in the same file that needs this function, but it sill doesn't link.

Comment: Actually, I just had to add `extern "C"` in case that helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do, is to have a timer running at 1khz, so it will generate an interrupt every millisecond, in the interrupt handler I increment a global var by one, say `ms_ticks` then do something like:

```
volatile unsigned int ms_ticks = 0;

void timer_isr() { //every ms
    ms_ticks++;
}

void delay(int ms) {
    ms += ms_ticks;
    while (ms > ms_ticks)
        ;
}
```

It is also possible to use this as a timestamp, so let's say I want to do something every 500ms:

```
last_action = ms_ticks;

while (1) {  //app super loop

    if (ms_ticks - last_action >= 500) {
        last_action = ms_ticks;
        //action code here
    }

    //rest of the code
}
```

Another alternative, since ARMs are 32bits and your timer will probably be a 32bits one, is to instead of generating a 1khz interrupt, you leave it free running and simply use the counter as your `ms_ticks`.

Comment: thanks for your answer!  do you have any good documentation on how to set up the timer and interrupt handler?  is this easy to do on the system?

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the timers in the chip...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Econotag which is based on the MC13224v from Freescale.

The MACA_CLK register provides a very good timebase (assuming the radio is running). You can also use the the RTC with CRM->RTC_COUNT. The RTC may or may not be very good depending on if you have an external 32kHz crystal or not (the econotag does NOT).

e.g. with MACA_CLK:

```
uint32_t t;

t = *MACA_CLK;

while (*MACA_CLK - t > SOMETIME);
```

See also the timer examples in libmc1322x:

http://git.devl.org/?p=malvira/libmc1322x.git;a=blob;f=tests/tmr.c

Alternate methods are to use etimers or rtimers in Contiki (which has good support for the Econotag). (see http://www.sics.se/contiki/wiki/index.php/Timers )